# hue said Resource Manager not available error but running fine

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, hue

when i run the quick start met the error message

```
Potential misconfiguration detected. Fix and restart Hue.

Resource Manager : Failed to contact an active Resource Manager: YARN RM returned a failed response: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8088): Max retries exceeded with url: /ws/v1/cluster/apps?user=hue (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

Hive : Failed to access Hive warehouse: /user/hive/warehouse

HBase Browser : The application won't work without a running HBase Thrift Server v1.

Impala : No available Impalad to send queries to.

Oozie Editor/Dashboard : The app won't work without a running Oozie server

Pig Editor : The app won't work without a running Oozie server

Spark : The app won't work without a running Livy Spark Server
```

i don't know why hue said error for resource manager.

i didn't install another things yet.

my resource manager is running and that api is no problem this - `http://RMHOST:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps?user=hue`

response is

```
{
 "apps": null
}
```

is there any problem i missed?

Answer (score 0):

I changed `localhost` to My IP address like `192.168.x.x` in `resourcemanager_host`, `resourcemanager_api_url`, `proxy_api_url`

I don't know why it works